# Get distinct combination of n elements with x variable combination of each in c#

Tags: c#

I have a dataset data representing items in a sql db:

[image]

I can have several rows for an item as I can have several suppliers able to provide it to me.

I'm getting these data and convert it to a list of objects:

```
    public class ItemBySupplier
    {
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public string Supplier { get; set; }
    }
```

So I have a list of this items in a variable :

```
List<ItemBySupplier> itemBySuppliers
```

I would like to iterate over this list to get all distinct combinations possible.

Where each combination should contains a distinct list of ALL items.

I know that I will have 4 combinations possible as only two items can be found in two different suppliers:

I'm expecting to outputs the same a list of the same objects (ItemBySupplier).

The desired output would be:

1. item1-supplierA / item2-**supplierB** / item3-supplierD / item4-**supplierE**
2. item1-supplierA / item2-**supplierC** / item3-supplierD / item4-**supplierE**
3. item1-supplierA / item2-**supplierB** / item3-supplierD / item4-**supplierF**
4. item1-supplierA / item2-**supplierC** / item3-supplierD / item4-**supplierF**

Any help would be much appreciate.

Comment: C# is a language of types. What is "a set of data" in C# type terms?

Comment: It's is somewhat awkward  and strange requirement from DB point of view to have all possible combinations as input... Are you looking for GroupBy? (Side note: you may want to [edit] the question to show data as text and what you already tried as lack of such information may lead to negative reception of the question)

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: I have edited the post, sorry if it was misleading. I'm using .NET Core 3.1

Comment: Depending on how you are getting the data, couldn't you just query distinct records?

Comment: I re-edited the post to simplify the sample and added the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

```
var items = itemBySuppliers.Select(d => d.Item).Distinct().OrderBy(t => t);
var a = items.Select(t => itemBySuppliers.Where(d => d.Item == t));

IEnumerable<IEnumerable<ItemBySupplier>> query = a.First().Select(e => new[] { e });

foreach (var e in a.Skip(1))
{
    query = query.Join(e, od => true, id => true, (ods, id) => ods.Concat(new[] { id }));
}

List<IEnumerable<ItemBySupplier>> combinations = query.ToList();
```

I hope this can help someone in the future.